# Python process locks main program

Tags: python, python-multithreading

So, I create a small program that uses flask to receive some requests and do a few things over selenium. All bits that deal with selenium are in another file that I tried to run first using a thread, and when it did not worked, a process. I believe that the problem is because I use a `while true` to keep my selenium working. The selenium part knows what to do because it keep checking the variable that I update from them flask part...

This is pretty much my main class that runs the selenium and them start flask, but it never start flask. It get locked on the `.start()`.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #   Logging
    log_format = '%(asctime)s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s'
    logging.basicConfig(format=log_format,
                        level=logging.INFO,
                        stream=sys.stdout)
    #   Start Selenium
    browser = Process(target=selenium_file.run_stuff())
    browser.start()
    print('TEST')
    #   Flask
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Not really sure how I could solve this problem (if it's a problem)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exchange `browser = Process(target=selenium_file.run_stuff())` with `browser = Process(target=selenium_file.run_stuff)`

You don't pass the function `run_stuff` but you already execute it and hence it blocks your program until `run_stuff` returns.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know that.